# Processing Java: Align text and ellipse

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to align a string of text and an ellipse vertically in *Processing*. Although both `textAlign` and `ellipseMode` are all set to `CENTER`, there is still a slight offset between the text and the ellipse.

```
void setup()
{
  size(200, 200);
  background(255);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);

  noStroke();
  smooth();
  fill(0);
  text("Document 1.txt", 60, 20);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(120, 20, 10, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `textAlign(CENTER)`, which specifies horizontal alignment, I used `textAlign(CENTER, CENTER)`, which guarantees that the text is aligned both horizontally, and vertically.